# How to change colors automatically once a parameter is changed

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code, the color of bars changes as the threshold is changed. Instead of using the threshold and plotting the horizontal line in the code, I want to use the y parameter in the OnMouseMove function so that the user can change the location of "threshold". Then, I want the colors to be updated as the y is changed.

I think what I need is called "observer pattern" or perhaps a trick using the animation tools but not sure how to implement it. I appreciate any insight on how to do this. Thanks

```
%matplotlib notebook
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.colors as mcol
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(335,1500,300), 
                   np.random.normal(410,900,300), 
                   np.random.normal(410,1200,300), 
                   np.random.normal(480,550,300)], 
                  index=[1,2,3,4])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.show()
bars = plt.bar(range(df.shape[0]), df.mean(axis = 1), color = 'lightslategrey')

fig = plt.gcf()
threshold=420
plt.axhline(y = threshold, color = 'grey', alpha = 0.5)

cm1 = mcol.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Test",["b", "white", "purple"])
cpick = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm1)
cpick.set_array([])

percentages = []
for bar in bars:
    percentage = (bar.get_height()-threshold)/bar.get_height()
    if percentage>1: percentage = 1
    if percentage<0: percentage=0
    percentages.append(percentage)

cpick.to_rgba(percentages)
bars = plt.bar(range(df.shape[0]), df.mean(axis = 1), color = cpick.to_rgba(percentages))
plt.colorbar(cpick, orientation='horizontal')

def onMouseMove(event):
    ax.lines = [ax.lines[0]]
    plt.axhline(y=event.ydata, color="k")

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', onMouseMove)

plt.xticks(range(df.shape[0]), df.index, alpha = 0.8)
```

Comment: What is the value of year_avg?

Comment: df.mean(axis = 1). Thanks. It was a mistake. Just corrected it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you should use exactly one bar plot and exactly one axhline (using more will make everything chaotic). You can set the colors of the bars via

```
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_color(..)
```

and you can update the axhline's position via `line.set_ydata(position)`.

Now, for every mouse move event you need to update the axhline's position, calculate the percentages and apply a new colors to the bars. So those things should be done in a function, which is called every time the mouse move event is triggered. After those settings have been applied the canvas needs to be drawn for them to become visible.

Here is a complete code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcol
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(335,1500,300), 
                   np.random.normal(410,900,300), 
                   np.random.normal(410,1200,300), 
                   np.random.normal(480,550,300)], 
                  index=[1,2,3,4])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

threshold=420.
bars = plt.bar(range(df.shape[0]), df.mean(axis = 1), color = 'lightslategrey')
axline = plt.axhline(y = threshold, color = 'grey', alpha = 0.5)

cm1 = mcol.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Test",["b", "white", "purple"])
cpick = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm1) 
cpick.set_array([])
plt.colorbar(cpick, orientation='horizontal')

def percentages(threshold):
    percentages = []
    for bar in bars:
        percentage = (bar.get_height()-threshold)/bar.get_height()
        if percentage>1: percentage = 1
        if percentage<0: percentage=0
        percentages.append(percentage)
    return percentages

def update(threshold):
    axline.set_ydata(threshold)
    perc = percentages(threshold)
    for bar, p in zip(bars, perc):
        bar.set_color(cpick.to_rgba(p))

# update once before showing
update(threshold)

def onMouseMove(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        update(event.ydata)
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', onMouseMove)

plt.xticks(range(df.shape[0]), df.index, alpha = 0.8)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Note that if you want to use this code in a jupyter notebook you need to use an interactive backend, `%matplotlib notebook`.